# Is Android NSD (Network Service Discovery) compatible with Bonjour service in iOS?

Tags: android, ios, bonjour, jmdns, mdns

I will create a server-less local networking App for iOS and Android. the App in both iOS and Android devices should find out and talk to each other.

I know that there are platform built-in services (which are Bonjour in iOS and NSD in Android since v4.1), in addition, a open source **jmdns** package can be used out of the box as well.

I don't know how to choose and how is their compatibility.

#### My questions are:

1. Is Android NSD (network service discovery) compatible with Bonjour in iOS?
   What should I use for service discovery in my App.
2. Do I need to use third-party lib if i also develop PC version for the App?

Comment: Have you made application using NSD in Android and Bonjour in iOS? Is it robust?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I developed similar project. Let me answer your questions:

1. Yes. [The official sample code](http://developer.android.com/training/connect-devices-wirelessly/nsd.html) should be able to make your quick start. Implement the function of service discovery is very easy. Only two steps: setting up a discovery listener with the relevant callbacks, and making a single asynchronous API call to discoverServices().
2. If you use the third-party library， **Advantage**: It can make your application works below Android 4.1；**Disadvantage**: Developing the function of service discovery would more complex. Because of you need write a background service to listen to broadcasts on the network.

Comment: Do you have PC version of your app? how to implement service discovery in your PC version of app?

Comment: On windows platform, we used [Apple Bonjour SDK](https://developer.apple.com/bonjour/). On Linux, we used [Avahi](http://avahi.org/). FYI.