# Automatic connection to a local network Android

Tags: android, ios, networking

So here is my problem. I'm making a multiplayer game (2 to 5 players) on Android, and at this moment it works perfectly. to send/receive data, i use kryonet and it works perfectly too.

The only problem i have is : for my game to work, i have to manually connect both devices to the same local network. I've already played multiplayer game, and they didn't need to connect to a same local network. So my question is: how to do it automatically? How to send data without being connected on a same local network?

On my research i found google play games services, but it requires to be loged. I've found wifi-direct, but it requires to manually enable it too.

ps: my solution needs to be portable for iOS

Thanks

Comment: If the players don't have to be on tne same network than an internet server will be used to distribute the messages. What is wrong with letting the user choose the local network?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21277805/is-android-nsd-network-service-discovery-compatible-with-bonjour-service-in-io