# Exchanging data over a WiFi Hotspot between an iOS device and Android device

Tags: android, ios

The problem is:

Having an Android device with turns on Personal Hotspot(WiFi/ad-hoc network).

Having an iOS device which connects to the Android's WiFi network.

Is there a possibility to exchange data between the same app build by a developer on both platforms?

If not, is there any way to exchange data between the same app running on both platforms using the current technologies on iOS and Android(so, without using internet connection or tech such as Near field communication)?

Already researched about data exchange using bluetooth which resulted in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18884705/transfer-data-between-ios-and-android-via-bluetooth).

Started researching about peer-to-peer connection but as its written on the first paragraph of the [Multipeer Connectivity](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MultipeerConnectivity/Reference/MultipeerConnectivityFramework/), it says "..by nearby iOS devices..".

(Android) [Wi-Fi Peer-to-Peer](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/wifip2p.html)

(iOS) [Multipeer Connectivity](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MultipeerConnectivity/Reference/MultipeerConnectivityFramework/)

Comment: Look at AllJoyn (google it) - library that runs on many OSes including Android and iOS.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21277805/is-android-nsd-network-service-discovery-compatible-with-bonjour-service-in-io

Comment: @David H thats a really good library, thanks a lot.

Comment: If the two phones are connected to the internet then of course they can communicate with each other through an app; you need to write the backend code that each app talks to, and share data that way. If you want two phones to talk _directly to each other_ without communicating via a 3rd party, then that has nothing to do with WiFi or a hotspot.

Answer (score -2):

Working on an application and there i am using the socket concept to send receive data from connected peer. All you need to do is

1. Create hotspot network
2. Allow nearby devices to connect
3. Send broadcast message like we send in chat. e.g User joined. And in that message send file which you want to download.
4. Other side in connected peer, Search file in local if exists use output stream to write the data and after writing the whole data just flush it to other side,
5. Active listener will receive the data in input stream then.

Hope it helps.